# What is the MySQL code I should use to draw from database?

Tags: mysql

I have two rows in MySQL, thus:

```
Row1: 123456 | 333333 | 222222
Row2: 123456 | 000000 | 000000
```

I want to check "123456" which is the data I input from the previous page form, and insert in Row2, whether can find it in Row1 which the data I preset in MySQL.

What is the MySQL code I should use to draw from database?

The following is my code:

```
SELECT ROW1,ROW2 FROM table WHERE ROW2 limit 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row[1]=$row[2])
{
echo 'the number you input is valid';
}
else
{
echo 'the number you input is not valid';
echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=index.php>';
}
```

Comment: Your paragraph beginning "I want to check ..." doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid - please edit your question and make it clearer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
if ($row[1]=$row[2])
```

you make a var allocation

try this

```
if ($row[1]==$row[2])
```

or if you compare the type and the value

```
if ($row[1]===$row[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it show: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in xxx.php on line 6 (which exactly if ($row[1]==$row[2]) line) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `mysql_fetch_row()` returns a zero based array, so the first field is in `$row[0]` and second in `$row[1]`.

Secondly, use the double equals comparison operator `==` to test for equality:

```
if ($row[0]==$row[1])
```

Finally, the `mysql_*` library is deprecated, it is recommended to upgrade to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Understand and thanks for your answer, however it still shows the error, I think I get wrong on "SELECT ROW1,ROW2 FROM table WHERE ROW2 limit 0,1" I want to use the value from previous page[$row2] and make compare in mysql. On the other hand, my first row is "sn", so exactly is $row[1] and $row[2]. Thank you very much

Comment: Are your fields really called `ROW1` and `ROW2`? To get data from a previous page you will need to store it in the session or pass as a GET or POST variable.